# Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-20.04

Need help
Whenever I try to perform `sudo apt-get install ****`
ex.

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential  
$ sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev  
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

When the command runs, a window pops up. I have attached the image of pop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssUt9.png)

Image includes:

```
Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                                                                                                                                                                                          │ 
 │ TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA                                                                                                                                                       
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE                                                                                                                                          
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for      
 │ the Microsoft software accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic documentation             
 │ ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to      
 │ the terms of this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.                                                                                                                              
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ SOFTWARE PRODUCT LICENSE The SOFTWARE PRODUCT is protected by copyright laws and international copyright treaties, as well as other intellectual property laws and treaties. The           
 │ SOFTWARE PRODUCT is licensed, not sold.                                                                                                                                                    
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ 1. GRANT OF LICENSE. This EULA grants you the following rights:                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │  • Installation and Use. You may install and use an unlimited number                                                                                                                       
 │    of copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.                                                                                                                                                      
 │  • Reproduction and Distribution. You may reproduce and distribute                                                                                                                         
 │    an unlimited number of copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT; provided                                                                                                                         
 │    that each copy shall be a true and complete copy, including all                                                                                                                         
 │    copyright and trademark notices, and shall be accompanied by a                                                                                                                          
 │    copy of this EULA. Copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT may not be                                                                                                                            
 │    distributed for profit either on a standalone basis or included                                                                                                                         
 │    as part of your own product.                                                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ 2. DESCRIPTION OF OTHER RIGHTS AND LIMITATIONS.                                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │  • Limitations on Reverse Engineering, Decompilation, and                                                                                                                                  
 │    Disassembly. You may not reverse engineer, decompile, or                                                                                                                                
 │    disassemble the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, except and only to the extent                                                                                                                         
 │    that such activity is expressly permitted by applicable law                                                                                                                             
 │    notwithstanding this limitation.                                                                                                                                                        
 │  • Restrictions on Alteration. You may not rename, edit or create                                                                                                                          
 │    any derivative works from the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, other than                                                                                                                              
 │    subsetting when embedding them in documents.                                                                                                                                            
 │  • Software Transfer. You may permanently transfer all of your                                                                                                                             
 │    rights under this EULA, provided the recipient agrees to the                                                                                                                            
 │    terms of this EULA.                                                                                                                                                                     
 │  • Termination. Without prejudice to any other rights, Microsoft may                                                                                                                       
 │    terminate this EULA if you fail to comply with the terms and                                                                                                                            
 │    conditions of this EULA. In such event, you must destroy all                                                                                                                            
 │    copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT and all of its component parts.                                                                                                                          
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ 3. COPYRIGHT. All title and copyrights in and to the SOFTWARE PRODUCT (including but not limited to any images, text, and "applets" incorporated into the SOFTWARE PRODUCT), the           
 │ accompanying printed materials, and any copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT are owned by Microsoft or its suppliers. The SOFTWARE PRODUCT is protected by copyright laws and international      
 │ treaty provisions. Therefore, you must treat the SOFTWARE PRODUCT like any other copyrighted material.                                                                                     
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ 4. U.S. GOVERNMENT RESTRICTED RIGHTS. The SOFTWARE PRODUCT and documentation are provided with RESTRICTED RIGHTS. Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is subject to          
 │ restrictions as set forth in subparagraph (c)(1)(ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer Software clause at DFARS 252.227-7013 or subparagraphs (c) (1) and (2) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted Rights at 48 CFR 52.227-19, as applicable. Manufacturer is Microsoft Corporation/One Microsoft Way/Redmond, WA 98052-6399.                       
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ LIMITED WARRANTY                                                                                                                                                                           
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ NO WARRANTIES. Microsoft expressly disclaims any warranty for the SOFTWARE PRODUCT. The SOFTWARE PRODUCT and any related documentation is provided "as is" without warranty of any         
 │ kind, either express or implied, including, without limitation, the implied warranties or merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose, or noninfringement. The entire risk           
 │ arising out of use or performance of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT remains with you.                                                                                                                
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ NO LIABILITY FOR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES. In no event shall Microsoft or its suppliers be liable for any damages whatsoever (including, without limitation, damages for loss of business     
 │ profits, business interruption, loss of business information, or any other pecuniary loss) arising out of the use of or inability to use this Microsoft product, even if Microsoft has     
 │ been advised of the possibility of such damages. Because some states/jurisdictions do not allow the exclusion or limitation of liability for consequential or incidental damages, the      
 │ above limitation may not apply to you.                                                                                                                                                     
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ MISCELLANEOUS                                                                                                                                                                              
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ If you acquired this product in the United States, this EULA is governed by the laws of the State of Washington.                                                                           
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ If this product was acquired outside the United States, then local laws may apply.                                                                                                         
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ Should you have any questions concerning this EULA, or if you desire to contact Microsoft for any reason, please contact the Microsoft subsidiary serving your country, or write:          
 │ Microsoft Sales Information Center/One Microsoft Way/Redmond, WA 98052-6399.                                                                                                               
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │ Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fontpack/eula.htm                                                                                                                           
 │                                                                                                                                                                                            
 │                                                                                          <Ok>
```

If I open a new terminal and try to run the same command again I get below errors:
E: `Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 21249 (apt-get)`
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: `Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV79z.png)

I tried the command `sudo kill 21249; sudo dpkg --configure -a`

No help,
It pop up the window again

Comment: Post text, no images.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Image information is added in the question above, please find. Thanku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update got interrupted and was causing issue.
I was trying to click OK but enter, return, arrows were not working. TAB key is used to click OK to accept the agreement.

Thankyou